# Django Extensions: ForeignKeyAutocompleteTabularInline doesn't work with model inheritance?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-extensions

Having defined my models as follows (example code):

```
class Category(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(...)

class Product(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(...)
    description = models.CharField(...)

class Drink(Product):
    # drink attributes

class Food(Product):
    # food attributes

class Relation(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

Using `ForeignKeyAutocompleteTabularInline` as an inline in a CategoryAdmin class to retrieve all kind of products (Drinks and Food) raises a `NoReverseMatch` exception because `app_product_changelist` isn't defined.

Is that the expected behavior? Any workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there should be an admin registered for the "Parent" model, based in `ForeignKeyAutocompleteAdmin`. After adding an extra ModelAdmin, the autocomplete seems to work fine.